# How to get the friendlist of someone when all you have is their facebook name, via get request

Tags: facebook

Say you have a facebook page like:

http://www.facebook.com/example.name.1

How can I programmatically get the friend list of this page via get request.

If I can test this using the facebook console it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to get your friends list. So, you can start from studying the following code.

```
$friends = $facebook->api("/me/friends")
```

Or you can also use the sql to retrieve the friends list.

```
$friends = $facebook->api(array(
"method"    => "fql.query",
"query"     => "SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())"
));
```